# Python - Replaying While Loop Dice Roll Game

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop, dice

How should I get the below loop to replay if the user types in an invalid response after being asked if they want to roll the dice again?

I can't get it to work without messing with the while loop. Here's what I have so far

```
# Ask the player if they want to play again

another_attempt = input("Roll dice again [y|n]?")

while another_attempt == 'y':

        roll_guess = int(input("Please enter your guess for the roll: "))
        if roll_guess == dicescore :
            print("Well done! You guessed it!")
            correct += 1
            rounds +=1
            if correct >= 4:
        elif roll_guess % 2 == 0:
            print("No sorry, it's", dicescore, "not", roll_guess)
            incorrect += 1
            rounds +=1
        else:
            print("No sorry, it's ", dicescore, " not ", roll_guess, \
                    ". The score is always even.", sep='')
            incorrect += 1
            rounds +=1
        another_attempt = input('Roll dice again [y|n]? ')

if another_attempt == 'n':
    print("""Game Summary""")


else:
    print("Please enter either 'y' or 'n'.")
```

Comment: What is currently the condition for the while loop? Can you think of something that will be true of `another_attempt` in every case that you want to loop, and also will be false in every case that you don't? Hint: what are you expecting the user to type in order to not try again?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do it with two while loops, and use functions to make the code logic more clear.

```
def play_round():
    # Roll dice
    # Compute score
    # Display dice
    # Get roll guess

def another_attempt():
    while True:
        answer = input("Roll dice again [y|n]?")
        if answer == 'y':
            return answer
        elif answer == 'n':
            return answer
        else:
            print("Please enter either 'y' or 'n'.")

def play_game():
    while another_attempt() == 'y':
        play_round()
    # Print game summary
```